# Swift: Why does a variable with a setter must also have a getter?

Tags: swift, setter, getter

Quick question: *why?*

---

Context:

Am using [Swinject](https://github.com/Swinject/Swinject) dependency injection to add **small-s** singleton model classes to my views thus:

```
defaultContainer.registerForStoryboard( MyViewController.self )
{
    responder, viewController in
    viewController.proxy = responder.resolve( MyProxy.self )!
}
```

I want to guard against the risk of accidentally overwriting this singleton instance by using a computed property thus:

```
private var _proxy: MyProxy!

var proxy: MyProxy 
{ 
    set { if _proxy == nil { _proxy = newValue } } 
}
```

But. I can't. Because I *must* also declare a getter.

*Frustrating!*

For now I am using the following hack. But really...

```
var proxy: MyProxy?
{
    get { return nil }
    set { if _proxy == nil && newValue != nil { _proxy = newValue } }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Quick answer for the quick question "*Why?*":

Once you add a `get` (or `set`) to a property, it turns into a [Computed Property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html). Computed properties may be **read-only**, thus requiring only a `get`*ter*, but they may **not** be write-only. So if you add a `set`*ter* to a property, you turn it into a computer property hence you **must** add a getter as well.

**EDIT:** Following comments, ***Why can Computed Properties be read-only, but not write-only?***

I can't find official documentation to back this up, so the following explanation is solely based on my logical point of view:

**Computed Properties don't store actual data on their variables**; instead they *compute* data to display.

```
var a:Int = 5 // Stored property
var timesTen:Int { // Computed Property
    get {
        return a * 10
    }
}
```

From the example above: `a` is a **Stored** property. Therefore, its `get` method automatically returns `a`'s value. Now think of `timesTen`: What's its value? Since it doesn't store any value in `timesTen` variable, you **must tell the computed property how and where to read its "value" from**. So that's why you can't use a computed property for writing-only purposes.

---

#### Workaround / How to avoid it

For simple properties you may use `didSet` or `willSet` to achieve the desired purpose:

```
var proxy: MyProxy?
{
    willSet { if _proxy == nil && newValue != nil { _proxy = newValue } }
}
```

If you are using Swift 2.x, you may use the [`guard`](http://www.codingexplorer.com/the-guard-statement-in-swift-2/) statement to for a cleaner code:

```
var proxy: MyProxy?
{
    willSet { 
         guard (_proxy == nil && newValue != nil) else { return }
         _proxy = newValue
    }
}
```

---

#### Another observation

If `_proxy` is not **required** to be `private` you may remove it completely, using only one variable/property instead of two:

```
var proxy: MyProxy!
{
    willSet { 
         guard (proxy == nil && newValue != nil) else { return }
         // By not preventing `willSet` to continue, `newValue` will automatically assigned to `proxy`
    }
}
```

Comment: "Computed properties ... may _not_ be write-only", but _why_?  That's what OP is asking, IMO.

Comment: Thank you @mathielo. Also: yes Anton Bronnikov I am still interested in the theory behind making computed properties not-write-only, but more importantly I have programming to get on with, and mathielo's answer has practical benefit. Thank you to you both.

Comment: @TheMotherofJosephBeuys updated the answer adding further details, please check it out.

Comment: @AntonBronnikov good point, I've updated the answer adding further explanation.

Comment: @TheMotherofJosephBeuys, oh, if I only knew you would accept an answer why you shouldn't do it :)

Answer (score 1):

Why cant you just return `_proxy` in your getter? What does that matter? If you are afraid of exposing your getter you can set your getter to private, thus exposing it only in the containing class.

```
private(get) var proxy: MyProxy? {
  set { if _proxy == nil && newValue != nil { _proxy = newValue } }
}
```

Comment: I guess @tskulbru. It feels hacky that way though. But thank you.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you can only use property observer `didSet` or `willSet`